# Receiving data from another app in xamarin,android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I had made an app using xamarin.android that plays with images. I want other app to share images to my app, I tried the following but throws exception.

Here is Android manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
          package="ReceiveDataFromApp.ReceiveDataFromApp" 
          android:versionCode="1" 
          android:versionName="1.0">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" />
  <application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity
       android:name=".MainActivity"
       android:label="@string/app_name">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Main.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
       />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.cs

```
namespace ReceiveDataFromApp
{
    [Activity(Label = "ReceiveDataFromApp", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);`

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.imageView);

            if (Intent.Data != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    var uri = Intent.Data;
                    var iis = ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(uri);
                    imageView.SetImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(iis));
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(this, e.Message, ToastLength.Long).Show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{ReceiveDataFromApp.ReceiveDataFromApp/ReceiveDataFromApp.ReceiveDataFromApp.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "ReceiveDataFromApp.ReceiveDataFromApp.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/ReceiveDataFromApp.ReceiveDataFromApp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/ReceiveDataFromApp.ReceiveDataFromApp-1/lib/arm, /data/app/ReceiveDataFromApp.ReceiveDataFromApp-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

Do correct what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution of the issue, thanks to @sushihangover

```
[Activity(Name = "ReceiveDataFromApp.ReceiveDataFromApp.MainActivty", Label = "ReceiveDataFromApp", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : Activity
~~~~
```

In manifest file you have to add:

```
<activity    
   android :name="ReceiveDataFromApp.ReceiveDataFromApp.MainActivity"
   android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Answer (score 3):

> ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "ReceiveDataFromApp.ReceiveDataFromApp.MainActivity"

By default, Xamarin creates MD5-based Java class names to avoid name clashing in the generated Java wrappers.

To hard-code a Java class name, use the `Name` parameter in the `ActivityAttribute`

```
[Activity(Name = "ReceiveDataFromApp.ReceiveDataFromApp.MainActivty", Label = "ReceiveDataFromApp", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : Activity
~~~~
```

Comment: Thanks SushiHangover for your hint but manifest fioe also requires the fully qualified name.

Answer (score 0):

The Android operating system uses content providers to facilitate access to shared data such as images, media files, contacts and so on. You can find how to use it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/content-providers/).

Comment: I think, you misunderstood the question, please read it carefully.

Comment: You want to SEND images ?

Comment: No, I want to receive images from gallery (via share option)

Comment: Did you noticed that you has a "`" char after your base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState); maybe that is the problem